# My xamarin application will not redirect after logging in to facebook

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I am new to xamarin forms, I've done plenty of searching on SO and google and cannot solve this problem that has had me stuck for a few days now.

I want the users of my mobile application to be able to login with Facebook.
I've followed the code example on https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/.
I have also setup my application of developers.facebook.com

I am debugging using an Android emulator via VS2017 with Xamarin.
I am writing a X platform app, so I have a PCL, Android and iOS project.
When I click my facebook login button, the facebook web UI displays as expected, when I log in, control does not return to the app.  It just sits on the facebook newsfeed for my facebook profile in an embedded browser.  The OAuth2Authenticator.Completed event never fires.  If I press the back button on my android device, it then DOES fire, but e.IsAuthenticated is false.

This is the code to launch the Facebook login

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(FaceBookAppId, "",
            new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
            new 
Uri("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));

        auth.Completed += Auth_Completed;
        auth.Error += Auth_Error;

        var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
        presenter.Login(auth);
```

I have a breakpoint sat on the event handler, but it never hits.

```
async void Auth_Completed(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //do some magic
    }
}
```

Not sure what I have done wrong.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more days of trying to solve this, it is quite clear that the Xamarin.Auth package is out of date.

I found that by deploying the release to an actual device, the login worked fine, but it did not function on an emulator.

I decided to go down the "manual" web based approach which is detailed in facebook dev docs here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

much more simple solution.